# onResume not called after app in background or phone sleep

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, onresume

I have problem with resuming my app - when it goes to background due to something else opened (for example I call intent to open a navigation), or because phone sleeps; after return (another activity closed or phone woked up) my app remains in background, on onResume is never called (no errors in log, nothing). Why is this happening and how can I get rid of this behavior, where I should start looking?

```
public class MainActivity extends ...v4.app.FragmentActivity implements FewMyListeners {
    . . .
    private Locator locator;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    try {
        locator = new Locator(this);
    } catch (NoLocationProviderFoundException e) {
        showLocationSettingsDialog();
    }

    refreshLocation();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if(locator != null) {
        locator.removeUpdates(false);
        locator = null;
    }

    dismissProgressDialog();

    super.onPause();
}
}

public class Locator implements LocationSource, LocationListener { . . . }
```

Comment: How do you actually know that `onResume()` is not called? I presume you already tried printing a log message from within that method (or any other method called by it) to be sure.

Comment: yup, I figured it out this way. When I run my app, onResume() is correcly called (and log printed). But after sleep or after moved to background nothing happens.

Comment: Does `onPause()` complete its execution successfully?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it does!

Comment: I see you're implementing a custom `LocationSource` for my-location layer in your `Locator` class. While _probably_ not the cause of the problem, I'd suggest letting the `GoogleMap` object manage the state of its location provider, as described in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/LocationSource.html).

Comment: I tried to put it out, but no change, it does not affect that behavior. I'm using own implementation of LocationSource, because I need to filter onLocationChanged and also turn notifications off for some time, gogols implementation is weird (as everything else :D)

Comment: Just noticed this.. what do you mean by "after return (...) my app remains in background"?

Comment: an example: in map I have pins and each pin acts as launcher for navigation (calls intent) - so after tap navigation is opened and when user closes that navigation, my app is not displayed, but instead user is brought to home screen. the same happens when phone goes to sleep within my app - after wake up my app is gone.

Comment: This is strange indeed.. It _looks_ like your app's `Activity`, instead of simply stopping, respectively pausing, is - for some reason - completely finishing. Did you try calling `isFinishing()` from `onPause()`, or printing a log message from `onDestroy()` to see what gives?

Comment: Sorry for delay, I worked on another project for some time. I tried to add some logging into onPause() and onDestroy() and results are as follows: just before super.onPause() is isFinishing() == false, but onDestroy() is called after onPause(). Is there some possibility to figure out why is this happens?

Comment: Since `onDestroy()` is called, it appears that Android is killing your app's `Activity` (process). Unfortunately I can't think of an explanation for this behavior.

Comment: So it looks like I have to create an empty project and add things one by one and test it :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was the most idiotic "bug" ever - noHistory set to true. Reset it to false did the trick:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:noHistory="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I do not think it was bug in your app. It is bug in android framework - why the hell should noHistory flag in any way affect whether onResume() is called or not? It should be ALWAYS called.

Comment: What about for fragments? Should I put that line for the activity that owns the fragment?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have called the `super.onResume()` method in your overridded `onResume()` method

Comment: I'm sure, it's the first line in my onResume() method.

Comment: post your onResume code .. and have you done anything extraordinary / abnormal task in activity? better paste your code

Comment: well, Im using standard (default one, I havent defined it), so I tried android:launchMode="singleInstance" because my application is just one activity, which switches fragments, but problem is still there :/. any other ideas?